# Using GET and POST for a search function in PHP

Tags: php, forms

I have a search box where the function is defined like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $orgname= $_POST['search'];
......
}
```

The POST search is coming via a form. I was wondering, is there a way to make this function accept a get value via a link too? For example, if I use the link like this: `mysite/page?search=value` , can I use `$orgname=$_GET['search']` to trigger the function, without submitting the form? So there will be two methods to load the data from the function, one is via submitting the form, the other is via the link as I mentioned above? Is this possible? I'm trying to do this because I have another tab on this page, where I have an update button where user can submit a form after making changes to the form data. But after the form is submitted, the update function works, but the page reloads and shows a blank form. I want to show the updated data when that form is submitted.

Comment: You could use method GET with a <form>, this is the default behavior => <form method="GET">

Comment: use $_REQUEST superglobal

Comment: @MineshPatel, Is $_REQUEST the best way to make this page search for the value again, after the form is submitted? Because now, when I submit the form, the page refreshed erasing the data, so the user has to manually key in the search value again and search, to see the updated data. or is there a way to load the updated data without moving away from the page, on form submit?

Comment: use ajax form submission

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have the same behavior for both `$_GET` and `$_POST` you can use the `$_REQUEST` superglobal.

If you want to know where your data is coming from, (wether it's a GET or POST request) you can simply check for the existence of the parameter on both arrays:

```
if(isset($_GET['search'])
{
     //We have a GET request
}
else if(isset($_POST['search'])
{
     //We have a POST request
}
else
{
     //Nothing found
}
```

Comment: Is `$_REQUEST` the best way to make this page search for the value again, after the form is submitted? Because now, when I submit the form, the page refreshed erasing the data, so the user has to manually key in the search value again and search, to see the updated data. or is there a way to load the updated data without moving away from the page, on form submit?

Comment: If you want asynchronous search then you need to run the script asynchronously with AJAX

Comment: using a seperate if `if(isset($_GET['search'])` worked

Answer (score 2):

You can use [$_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

`$_REQUEST` — HTTP Request variables

An associative array that by default contains the contents of `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`.